# Lavarel project with nginx server return 404|Not Found but works fine with default /var/www/html root

Tags: laravel, nginx, http-status-code-404

I am struggling in this problem almost 1 day. I have VPS with LEMP (Laravel, nginx, Php and mySQL) and lavarel project is stored as /var/www/html/api. My config file is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html/api/public;
    #root /var/www/html; //ok

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name ipaddress;
    client_max_body_size 64M;
    location / {

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {

            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
```

}

Thanks a lot and any help would be appreciative.

Comment: Did you give permission to storage?

Comment: Hi Ahsan, Thanks a lot for your prompt response. I did give permission to storage (775)  it is [drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Jun 15 01:35 storage].

Comment: Hi, your nginx config file looks ok. So just to be sure, the permission was recursive, right?

Comment: Hi @Ahsan: yes, it's right. I also checked all the nginx operation (service is running, php-fpm is running and in /var/log/nginx/error.log has only [signal process started].

Comment: Hi, I am not sure, but for some reason putting your app inside html does not work. May be there is a work around, but I have not found it yet. I put my apps in /var/www folder and it works. If you make root as /var/www/api/public, I think it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ahsan. It was also fine when I copied index.html into /var/www/api/public. Maybe the problem inside the code. I will try to debug it. Thanks a lot.